# jquery highlight every second table row

Tags: jquery, row, highlight

Hi guys i just started with jquery, I wonder how to solve that problem:

I try to highlight each row in the table by clicking checkbox, everything is fine except for that only every second row is highlighted.

```
    $('tr').on('click',':checkbox', function () {
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlighted');   
            } else {
              $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlighted');    
            }
```

I found that attached css link 

causes this problem. Unfortunately I can't ignore it.
I tried also toggleClass but without success.

How can I highlight every checked row in a table with a use of above mentioned css file?

Comment: can you share the css rule associated with `highlighted`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/STF2b/1/ also http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/STF2b/2/

Comment: .highlighted {
            background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.7);
        }

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css"> - this causes problem

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/STF2b/3/

Comment: unfortunatelly this syntax also selects every second row

Comment: can you try to recreate the issue in the attached fiddle

Comment: my or your code is fine, the problem is with  <table class="pure-table-bordered pure-table pure-table-striped">, these classes make problem

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/STF2b/4/

Comment: nothing changed, when I remove only pure-table-striped class everything is fine.CSS  - .pure-table-striped tr:nth-child(2n-1) td{background-color:#f2f2f2}

Comment: Thx no is ok :) I forgot to change CSS rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the pure-api, has a higher precedence rule `.pure-table-striped tr:nth-child(2n-1) td{}` which is setting the background color, so your rule is overriden by that rule. The solution is to fine tune your rule like

```
.highlighted, .pure-table-striped tr.highlighted td {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/STF2b/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post all the rules from your css stylesheet that can affect the rendering of rows on your page ?

If you have some code that give an `even / odd` class to each row, one way to have the `highlighted` rule apply with higher priority than the `even / odd` rule is to specify it twice, e.g. :

```
//replace
tr.highlighted { background-color: purple }

//with
tr.even.highlighted, tr.odd.highlighted { background-color: purple }
```